# Is there any way to create multipage TIFF file with OJPEG (TIFFTAG_COMPRESSION = 6) compression using .NET?

Tags: .net, image-processing, tiff, libtiff.net

I need to create multipage TIFF file with OJPEG(Old-style JPEG) compression from single page tiffs with the same compression scheme.
I understand that this type of compression is not widely used anymore, but my customers deal with Microsoft Office Document Imaging (MODI) application and they can not use another software. There is a known bug described in this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/885938 - MODI works okay with LZW-compressed tiffs, but those files are too large.
I tried to use LIbTiff.NET library, but looks like it supports only decompression, not compression. Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using OJPEG is strongly discouraged for more than **20 years** already (since June 3, 1992). And there is a reason for this: the OJPEG spec is misleading in many ways and almost every  compressor implemented the spec wrong.

You might want to change your requirements. If there is absolutely no other ways then you might try and implement some code that just glues given files together.

It should not be **very** hard (you will need to copy images into one file and update directory chain accordingly). Anyway, it might be very frustrating experience, especially if files you should deal with are coming from different compressors.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Actually, I consider the way you proposed ("copy images into one file and update directory chain accordingly") to be the one and only I can use, because we can't change requirements. Thanks again!